# How to convert text SID to SID structure in Windows kernel driver?

Tags: driver, wdk, windows-kernel

My kernel driver should read a SID in text format from registry and convert it to SID structure for subsequent usage.

Are there any [ConvertStringSidtoSid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa376402(v=vs.85).aspx) analogue for kernel driver?

I know I may parse text and construct it by hand, but it looks like usual task.
Cannot find anything by search.

Comment: I suggest you move all user-mode API dependent functionality to a user-mode component (eg. a service). Also, read [Calling a DLL in a Kernel-Mode Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Dn613893(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Remus Rusanu construct SID from text representation is not big deal, adding user-mode component will be definitely overkill. I'm just asking may be ready to use solution exists.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody answer my questions and I did write some code and want to share it.

It worked for all my use cases. May be it will be useful to somebody:

```
BOOLEAN
IprParseSubAuthorities(
    _In_ PCWCHAR buffer,
    _Out_ PISID pSid
)
{
    ULONG authority = 0;
    UCHAR count = 0;
    for (USHORT i = 0;; i++)
    {
        if ((buffer[i] >= L'0') && (buffer[i] <= L'9'))
        {
            authority = authority * 10 + (buffer[i] - L'0');
            continue;
        }
        else if (buffer[i] == L'-')
        {
            pSid->SubAuthority[count] = authority;
            authority = 0;

            if (++count >= pSid->SubAuthorityCount)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if (buffer[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    pSid->SubAuthority[count] = authority;
    return TRUE;
}

UCHAR IprGetSubAuthorityCount(
    _In_ PCWCHAR buffer
)
{
    UCHAR count = 1; // buffer should contains at least one authority
    for (UCHAR i = 0;; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == L'-')
        {
            count++;
        }
        else if (buffer[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

BOOLEAN
IprConvertUnicodeSidtoSid(
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING UnicodeSid,
    _Out_ PISID* ppSid
)
{
    PCWCHAR PREFIX = L"S-1-5-";
    const USHORT PREFIX_LEN = (USHORT)wcslen(PREFIX);
    SIZE_T result = RtlCompareMemory(PREFIX, UnicodeSid->Buffer, PREFIX_LEN);
    if (result != PREFIX_LEN)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    UCHAR subAuthorityCount =
        IprGetSubAuthorityCount(UnicodeSid->Buffer + PREFIX_LEN);

    PISID pSid = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(SID) + sizeof(ULONG) * (subAuthorityCount - 1));

    pSid->Revision = 1;
    pSid->IdentifierAuthority.Value[0] = 0;
    pSid->IdentifierAuthority.Value[1] = 0;
    pSid->IdentifierAuthority.Value[2] = 0;
    pSid->IdentifierAuthority.Value[3] = 0;
    pSid->IdentifierAuthority.Value[4] = 0;
    pSid->IdentifierAuthority.Value[5] = 5;
    pSid->SubAuthorityCount = subAuthorityCount;

    if (!IprParseSubAuthorities(UnicodeSid->Buffer + PREFIX_LEN, pSid))
    {
        ExFreePool(pSid);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!RtlValidSid(pSid))
    {
        ExFreePool(pSid);
        return FALSE;
    }

    *ppSid = pSid;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: How do you use it? You need to initialize the ppSid beforehand